# Running webpack with custom command

Tags: webpack, bundler

Is there a way to run webpack to build file differently. What I mean is, e.g of my directory:

```
src/
   A/
    css/
    js/
      index.js
   B/
    css/
    js/
      index.js
dist/
   A/
    bundle.js
   B/
    bundle.js
```

Is there a such way to configure webpack and make a command like `webpack A` to build A files only and output it in `dist/A` and `webpack B` to build B files. It's like `gulp.task` way.

Answer (score 0):

In you webpack config, you can use the name bundler tag `[name]`:

```
entry: {
    a: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, './a/js/index')
    ],
    b: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, './b/js/index')
    ]
},
target: 'web',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/[name]',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
```

You can split the configs, so you can:

webpack.a.config.js:

```
entry: {
    a: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, './a/js/index')
    ]
},
target: 'web',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/[name]',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
```

and

webpack.b.config.js:

```
entry: {
    b: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, './b/js/index')
    ]
},
target: 'web',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/[name]',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
```

In you gulp file you can do:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('build:a', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
               .pipe(webpack( require('./webpack.a.config.js') ))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/a/'));
});

gulp.task('build:b', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
               .pipe(webpack( require('./webpack.b.config.js') ))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/b/'));
});
```

taken from [usage with gulp](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html)

And you should just be able to run:

```
gulp build:a
gulp build:b
```

### Share webpack configs

To share configs, you will be a `webpack.base.config.js` and the other two js.

Then you can do a simple `Object.assign` to merge them in the gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');

var a = require('./webpack.a.config.js');
var b = require('./webpack.b.config.js');
var base = require('./webpack.base.config.js');

gulp.task('build:a', function() {
    var fullConfig = Object.assign({}, base, a);

    return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
               .pipe(webpack(fullConfig))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/a/'));
});

gulp.task('build:b', function() {
    var fullConfig = Object.assign({}, base, b);

    return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
               .pipe(webpack(fullConfig ))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/b/'));
});
```

Comment: That config will build all files when I execute webpack command right? Mine current config is like that too. But how about to make a custom command that only run at specific entry ? Like `webpack a` only entry 'a' will be build. Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: Oh, I don't think you can, but you can split the config, give me 10mins!